# KeyUp event not firing until I ALT+Tab away then back to my application

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard

I am experiencing a very strange issue with my Windows Forms form. As stated in the title, the KeyUp event is not firing in the application at all until I alt+tab away from the window, then back. Doesn't matter where I click in the application before switching away; nothing happens.

Also if I alt-tab away from the application, but click on the app's task bar to switch back, then I still don't get KeyUp events. Clicking away, then alt-tabbing back, makes the KeyUp event function properly again.

Seems I only get KeyUp events if I Alt-Tab TO the application - but not in any other case.

The KeyPreview property is `true`. I'm not doing any other key processing in the application anywhere - just in the KeyUp event.

I really need this application to be able to respond to KeyUp events, especially just after startup - I don't want to instruct my users to alt-tab away then back just to have keyboard input function properly. Has anyone seen this issue and found a workaround?

---

**Update:** I've tinkered around with this a bit more, and I found a workaround - but it's definitely a kludge and I don't like it. In the `OnShown` override for the form, I added a call to `this.Focus();`. I also added an event handler for `this.LostFocus` that also calls `this.Focus();`. This is the only form in this application, so none of that is a problem - I just wish I understood **why** this is happening. =( Ah well.

I added this as an update instead of an answer because, well, this *isn't* an answer. Bleh.

Comment: Does it happen on more than one machine? What about with a brand new WinForms app?

Comment: KeyUp only fires if a control that can take keyboard focus receives a KeyDown. IOW, the form itself doesn't normally receive keystrokes - controls such as edits and list/comboboxes do. That's why using `this.Focus();` is a workaround; you're forcing something that doesn't normally get keyboard focus to take it anyway.

Comment: Ken - is there an *official* way to deal with this problem? `this.Focus()` feels too much like a kludge. =(

Comment: Erik: I suspect `this.Focus()` is the way to go. Typically, the focus will go to the first control on the form (the one that's at the head of the tab order). It appears that, if there are no controls on the form, the form itself doesn't get the focus. So you'll have to set it.

Comment: This form is all information display - no input-focusable controls. And it seems my workaround isn't 100% foolproof either. =\ @shambulator - this doesn't happen with a new app, and it does happen on every machine I put it on, so it's definitely something wrong with my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up on using form events - I'm now registering a global Windows hotkey for the key sequence I want to trap, and that's working just fine. It doesn't matter in my case that the hotkey is global, as my application is designed to be the only one in use on this system.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828964

I've overridden the form's ProcessCmdKey() method in order to 'receive' the accelerator keys in the form first.